# Issue with file upload in java

Tags: java, file-upload, chunks

I am trying to upload 6GB file and my application restricts up to 6GB to upload. There is a timeout error that I get. The logic includes normal chunking the files and uploading sequentially. My question might be bit foolish but I want to know does parallel processing of these chunks will really solve the problem for file size of 6GB and is it really required. The timeout error sometimes cannot be reproduced but do happen for some users and could depend on network bandwidth. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: If there is a chunking mechanism surely the application can either send smaller chunks &/or retry when the chunk fails to upload?  If the problem is related to bandwidth, sending more chunks in parallel is going to make the problem worse (less bandwidth to share) than make it better ...   But I have to wonder 6GB - could the application not gzip the data or similar first?

Comment: There is no gzip done. It too happens when one uploads 2 or 3GB file it is throwing time out or it sometimes stops with out any error.